# json.net: serialise base class members first

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using json.net to store a serialised object that I would like people to be able to edit in a text editor. I have a base class that contains the name of the object and then a class that inherits from that and adds some other properties.

The problem is that the the properties are written out such that the derived classes properties are written first, and then the base class afetr, so I get:

```
{
  "MySpecialFiled": 4,
  "Name": "This Is My Object",
  "AnotherBaseField": 8,
}
```

rather than:

```
{
  "Name": "This Is My Object",
  "AnotherBaseField": 8,
  "MySpecialFiled": 4,
}
```

You can see how this get's a bit of a pain when you have a bunch of fields in the derived class and want to actually view/edit in a text editor!

I've messed around with the source code particularly:

```
public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetFields(Type targetType, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
```

and

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(Type targetType, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
```

in ReflectionUtils.cs, to try and reverse the order so that base class properties come first, but I've not had any success yet. Am I missing something trivial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer of @sinelaw does not work because property `Order` returns null unless you set up your properties with `[JsonProperty(Order = <someInteger>)]` which kinds of defeat the purpose of using a custom sort instead of using `JsonProperty` attributes.

I have modified its `CustomPropertySortContractResolver` to use default properties order when this order is not found.

> ```
> public class CustomPropertySortContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
> {
>     private const int MaxPropertiesPerContract = 1000;
>
>     protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
>     {
>         var members = GetSerializableMembers(type);
>         if (members == null)
>         {
>             throw new JsonSerializationException("Null collection of serializable members returned.");
>         }
>
>         var propList = members
>             .Select(member => CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization))
>             .Where(x => x != null);
>
>         var ind = 0;
>         var orderedPropList = propList
>             .OrderBy(p => ((p.Order != null ? p.Order : ind++) + (MaxPropertiesPerContract * GetTypeDepth(p.DeclaringType)) ?? -1))
>             .ToList();
>
>         return orderedPropList;
>     }
>
>     private static int GetTypeDepth(Type type)
>     {
>         int depth = 0;
>         while ((type = type.BaseType) != null)
>         {
>             depth++;
>         }
>
>         return depth;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to change JSON.Net's code to do it. Apparently you can do it with a custom contract resolver - by inheriting from [DefaultContractResolver](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm) - as shown in **[this code pasted by someone with a similar issue](http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/352825)** on the json.net forum. That poster overrides `CreateProperties` and sorts the properties by how deeply inherited the defining type is.

The following code is based on code from that post (by [LittleColin](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/LittleColin) on CodePlex). This **compiles but isn't tested**:

```
public class CustomPropertySortContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private const int MaxPropertiesPerContract = 1000;

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var members = GetSerializableMembers(type);
        if (members == null)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Null collection of serializable members returned.");
        }

        return members.Select(member => CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization))
                      .Where(x => x != null)
                      .OrderBy(p => (p.Order
                                       + (MaxPropertiesPerContract * GetTypeDepth(p.DeclaringType))) 
                                    ?? -1)
                      .ToList();
    }

    private static int GetTypeDepth(Type type)
    {
        int depth = 0;
        while ((type = type.BaseType) != null)
        {
            depth++;
        }

        return depth;
    }
}
```

See also [this project](https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/JsonDotNetCustomContractResolvers) for similar code that filters the properties to be serialized.

Comment: That's kind of useful, but I think the code is out of date? properties.OrderBy() doesn't work because OrderBy() is not a member of JsonProipertyCollection (which inherits from KeyedCollection). I have hacked some pre-sorting of the List of MemberInfo, but I wonder if there's a trick I'm issing.

Comment: @steeveeet - I've updated the code to match json.net v4.5 and cleaned it up a bit. It compiles but I did not test it.

Comment: Code doesn't work. If the code is not tested, it shouldn't be posted here.

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement, I have suggested another approach different than accepted answer using `[JsonProperty(Order = -2)]` here:

[Order of fields when serializing the derived class in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571695/order-of-fields-when-serializing-the-derived-class-in-json-net/45690162#45690162)

Comment: That assumes that the base class hasn't already done this trick for some reason, meaning that my class would then need to have Order = -3. I could see this getting messy, e.g. if the author of the base class suddenly decided to start doing this then all inherited classes would need to be modified to take account of that.