# Order of fields when serializing the derived class in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Consider these two classes:

```
public Class Base {
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

And the derived class:

```
public Class Derived : Base {
    public string Address {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
}
```

When serializing the *Derived class* using *Json.Net*:

```
Derived record = new Derived record(); {// Initialize here...}
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(record);
```

By default, the properties of the *Derived class* appear first:

```
{ 
  "address": "test", 
  "date_of_birth" : "10/10/10",
  "id" : 007,
  "name" : "test name",
  "last_name": "test last name"
 }
```

What I need:

```
{ 
  "id" : 007,
  "name" : "test name",
  "last_name": "test last name"
  "address": "test", 
  "date_of_birth" : "10/10/10",      
 }
```

**Question**

Is it possible to have the *base class* properties come first, when serializing the derived class (**without using `[JsonProperty(Order=)]` for each property of both classes**)?

Comment: Is it worth asking the question "why do you need the order to be different?"

Comment: @TimBarrass Just to be more organized when manual testing and debugging.

Comment: According to the [JSON standard](http://json.org/), a JSON object is an * unordered set of name/value pairs*.  So my recommendation would be to not worry about this.

Comment: For testing of JSON, I find [`JToken.DeepEquals`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_DeepEquals.htm) to be very useful, it eliminates differences due purely to formatting.

Comment: What can't you use the Order= attribute?

Comment: @MarcBernier It's so complicated; this is a shared model which is being used by other teams, they cannot use any attributes. Also our class has so many properties and we use multi-level inheritance, (so the array of json objects sometimes have many name/value pairs) sometimes it gets difficult to compare the results if it's not in order. (by testing I actually meant quickly checking and comparing some values of the records.)

Comment: I don't think the 'Order' numbers have to be sequential. Maybe you could allocate 'bands' for each child (ie, base is 1-10, child A is 11-20, child B is 21-30, etc).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the [JSON standard](https://json.org/), a JSON object is an *unordered set of name/value pairs*.  So my recommendation would be to not worry about property order.  Nevertheless you can get the order you want by creating your own [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) inheriting from one of the standard [contract resolvers](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm), and then overriding [`CreateProperties`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateProperties.htm):

```
public class BaseFirstContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) =>
        base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization)
            ?.OrderBy(p => p.DeclaringType.BaseTypesAndSelf().Count()).ToList();
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
// Cache an instance of the resolver for performance
static IContractResolver baseFirstResolver = new BaseFirstContractResolver { /* Set any required properties here e.g.  NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy() */ };

// And use the cached instance when serializing and deserializing
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    ContractResolver = baseFirstResolver, 
    // Add your other settings here.
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects 
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(derived, typeof(Base), Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Notes:

- This approach works especially well with multi-level type hierarchies as it automates correct ordering of properties from all levels in the hierarchy.
- Newtonsoft recommends [caching instances of contract resolvers](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver) for best performance.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zdo3zP).

Comment: it probably makes sense to cache type level since your are going to calculate it for each property in the same class

Answer (score 54):

Just as a complement, another approach different than the accepted answer is using `[JsonProperty(Order = -2)]`; You can modify your base class as follow:

```
public class Base
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = -2)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = -2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = -2)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The reason of setting Order values to -2 is that every property without an explicit Order value has a value of -1 by default. So you need to either give all child properties an Order value, or just set your base class' properties to -2.

Comment: I think `[JsonProperty(Order = int.MinValue)]` is self explanatory (-2 appears to be an arbitrary value)

Comment: Yes but in the question, I mentioned without using [JsonProperty(Order=)] for each property of both classes. The reason is I was working on a multiplatform project that the `[JsonProperty]` attribute was not available to use.

Comment: You're right. As I mentioned, it was just a complementary answer for those who may find this question merely by its title, which is more general. So both approaches can be find in one place.

Comment: Alternately, my derived class added just one property to the base class. I found easier and cleaner to add [JsonProperty(Order = 1)] to that property in the derived class

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ASP.NET Core, don't override important contract resolver settings [provided by default](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonSerializerSettingsProvider.cs).  Following from @dbc's answer, you can do this:

```
class DataContractJsonResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public DataContractJsonResolver()
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy();
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties( Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization )
    {
        return base.CreateProperties( type, memberSerialization )
            .OrderBy( p => BaseTypesAndSelf( p.DeclaringType ).Count() ).ToList();

        IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf( Type t )
        {
            while ( t != null ) {
                yield return t;
                t = t.BaseType;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also consider taking 'dbc's answer, but with the replacement of the 'OrderBy()' expression, with the following (- that does not rely upon the base-class having more properties than the derived one):

```
                    .OrderBy(
                        p =>
                            p.DeclaringType == type
                                ? 2
                                : 1)
                    .ThenBy(
                        p =>
                            p.Order ?? -1)
```

And then you don't need the "TypeExtensions", but it is repeating the 'p.Order' ordering (that has already taken place within the base class); given time & thought, there might be a better/more efficient way to do this.

Comment: I'm not ordering by *number of properties* I am ordering by ***depth of the `DeclaringType` in the type hierarchy***.

Comment: But you've got a (final) call to '.Count()' in the 'OrderBy()' call.

Comment: `DeclaringType.BaseTypesAndSelf().Count()` counts the number of base types in the inheritance hierarchy of the declaring type.  A smaller count means that the property was declared higher up in the inheritance hierarchy (i.e. is from a base type), while a larger count means the property is from a more derived type.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ordered properties "as is" from the base classes first like so:

```
public List<PropertyInfo> GetOrderedProperties(Type type)
{
    // Only get the properties for the current type and not its base type
    List<PropertyInfo> results = (type as TypeInfo)
            .DeclaredProperties
            .Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.CanRead && propertyInfo.CanWrite)
            .ToList();

    // Modify the above to your liking, but this presumes you want to add
    // every property that can be read and written to.

    // Insert the base type properties before the current type's properties
    if (type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType != typeof(object))
    {
        // Recursive method call
        results.InsertRange(0, GetOrderedProperties(type.BaseType));
    }

    return results;
}
```

Then create a custom `JsonConverter` ([Custom JsonConverter example here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)):

```
public class OrderedPropertiesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    //...
    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer,
        object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer
    )
    {
        if (value is null) {
            writer.WriteNullValue();
            return;
        }

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var property in GetOrderedProperties(typeof(value)))
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(property.Name);
            writer.WriteValue(property.GetValue(value));
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public List<PropertyInfo> GetOrderedProperties(Type type)
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> results = (type as TypeInfo)
                .DeclaredProperties
                .Where(propertyInfo =>
                    propertyInfo.CanRead
                    && propertyInfo.CanWrite)
                .ToList();

        if (type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType != typeof(object))
        {
            results.InsertRange(0, GetOrderedProperties(type.BaseType));
        }
    
        return results;
    }
    //...
}
```

Then use your custom `OrderedPropertiesConverter` converter:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contacts,new OrderedPropertiesConverter());
```