# Order property of derived class first in Swagger schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, swagger

I use, among others, Json.NET and NSwag and generate a swagger document. I have classes, `Animal` and `Dog : Animal` (inherits from `Animal`).

```
public class Animal
{
    //properties
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = -2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have property in `Dog`, which is `Name`. I want to sort `Name` before all of `Dog`'s properties **in the generated Swagger request schema.**

Current result:

```
{
   propertyOne: value1, //property of Animal
   propertyTwo: value2, //property of Animal
   Name: value3 //property of Dog
}
```

Desired result:

```
{
   Name: value3, //property of Dog is sorted before everything else
   propertyOne: value1,
   propertyTwo: value2
}
```

Comment: Curious to know what the reasoning is behind it..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of fields when serializing the derived class in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571695/order-of-fields-when-serializing-the-derived-class-in-json-net)

Comment: @AkshayG Unfortunately not, since that person want's the base-class first, not the derived class.

Comment: So u are saying his problem is your solution?.. check by default how does it serialise .. The solution still holds good irrespective of what the problem you have

Comment: @AkshayG Yes, their problem is my solution, but as far as I can see, they are trying to deserialize the JSON (call to `.Serialize(object);`), whereas I am trying to have it represented correctly in the Swagger schema, but I am not calling serialize on it.

Comment: *serialize the JSON

Answer (score 2):

I have done similar sorting but in Swashbuckle, might be similar functionality available in Nswag

Used SchemaFilter to sort properties.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(swaggerGenOptions =>
{
.....

swaggerGenOptions.SchemaFilter<SwaggerSchemaFilter>();
}
```

In schemaFilter, I have used order logic to show all the basic datatype properties in their current oreder and properties which are custom classes in the end. But you can order by name or any other logic.

```
internal class SwaggerSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            schema.Properties = schema.Properties
                .OrderBy(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Value.Type) ? "z" : "a")
                .ToDictionary(p2 => p2.Key, p2 => p2.Value);
        }
}
```

For custom classes the type was null,

Also, you can get type from (SchemaFilterContext) context and use reflection to get more details.